# Combining dataframes with missing values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have several dataframes with data from the same survey. I want to combine them for analysis. The dataframes contain both unique variables and two variables (ID and Contest_no) that are shared across all the dataframes; the two shared variables contain information about the respondent and the contest number (1,2,3, as respondents were asked the same questions three times).

The difficulty is that the dataframes have missing values:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
             V2 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
             ID = factor(c("x1", "x1", "y2", "y2")),
             Contest_no = factor(c("1", "2", "1", "2")))

DF2 <- data.frame(V3 = factor(c("A", "C", "D")),
                  V4 = factor(c("A", "C", "D")),
                  ID = factor(c("x1", "y2", "y2")),
                  Contest_no = factor(c("1", "1", "2")))

DF3 <- data.frame(V5 = factor(c("A", "B", "C")),
                  V6 = factor(c("A", "B", "C")),
                  ID = factor(c("x1", "x1", "y2")),
                  Contest_no = factor(c("1", "2", "1")))
```

As a result, respondent IDs and contest numbers aren't aligned. I want to match the data to respondent IDS and contest numbers so that the merged dataframe looks like this:

```
DF_merged <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
                    V2 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
                    V3 = factor(c("A", NA, "C", "D")),
                    V4 = factor(c("A", NA, "C", "D")),
                    V5 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", NA)),
                    V6 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", NA)),
                    ID = factor(c("x1", "x1", "y2", "y2")),
                    Contest_no = factor(c("1", "2", "1", "2")))
```

I thought that `full_join` would do the trick, but `DF_merged <- full_join(DF1, DF2, DF3, by="ID")` gives me nonsensical results.

How can disparate data like this be combined?

New, updated example (to address the problem of multiplied rows). In this example there are no missing values at all, and both dataframes have the same number of rows, but the code results in multiplied rows. First, the two dataframes to be merged:

df1:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("EE1", "EE101", "EE102"), class = "factor"), 
    Contest_no = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L), Option = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Option1", "Option2"), class = "factor"), 
    Chosen_option = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L), Combination = structure(c(5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("V133", "V181", "V234", 
    "V252", "V32", "V67"), class = "factor"), Attribute1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("has strong ties to the government", 
    "has weak ties to the government"), class = "factor"), Attribute2 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("has strong ties to the local pastoralist community", 
    "has weak ties to the local pastoralist community"), class = "factor"), 
    Attribute3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("is poor", "is wealthy"), class = "factor"), 
    Attribute4 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("has attained a high level of formal education (for example university degree)", 
    "has not attained a high level of formal education (for example never went to school or only attended primary school)"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Contest_no", "Option", 
"Chosen_option", "Combination", "Attribute1", "Attribute2", "Attribute3", 
"Attribute4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

df2:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("EE1", "EE101", "EE102"), class = "factor"), 
    Contest_no = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L), Option = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Option1", "Option2"), class = "factor"), 
    Chosen_option = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L), Combination = structure(c(6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("V150", "V249", "V252", 
    "V29", "V56", "V77"), class = "factor"), Attribute1 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("has strong ties to the government", 
    "has weak ties to the government"), class = "factor"), Attribute2 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("has strong ties to the local pastoralist community", 
    "has weak ties to the local pastoralist community"), class = "factor"), 
    Attribute3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("is poor", "is wealthy"), class = "factor"), 
    Attribute4 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("has attained a high level of formal education (for example university degree)", 
    "has not attained a high level of formal education (for example never went to school or only attended primary school)"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Contest_no", "Option", 
"Chosen_option", "Combination", "Attribute1", "Attribute2", "Attribute3", 
"Attribute4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

and now the unsuccessful attempt to combine the two dataframes:

```
df_merge_attempt <- dplyr::full_join(df1, df2, by=c("ID","Contest_no"))
```

results in:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("EE1", "EE101", "EE102"), class = "factor"), Contest_no = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Option.x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Option1", "Option2"), class = "factor"), 
    Chosen_option.x = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    Combination.x = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L), .Label = c("V133", "V181", "V234", "V252", "V32", "V67"
    ), class = "factor"), Attribute1.x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("has strong ties to the government", 
    "has weak ties to the government"), class = "factor"), Attribute2.x = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("has strong ties to the local pastoralist community", 
    "has weak ties to the local pastoralist community"), class = "factor"), 
    Attribute3.x = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("is poor", "is wealthy"), class = "factor"), 
    Attribute4.x = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("has attained a high level of formal education (for example university degree)", 
    "has not attained a high level of formal education (for example never went to school or only attended primary school)"
    ), class = "factor"), Option.y = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Option1", "Option2"), class = "factor"), 
    Chosen_option.y = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
    Combination.y = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("V150", "V249", "V252", "V29", "V56", "V77"
    ), class = "factor"), Attribute1.y = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("has strong ties to the government", 
    "has weak ties to the government"), class = "factor"), Attribute2.y = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("has strong ties to the local pastoralist community", 
    "has weak ties to the local pastoralist community"), class = "factor"), 
    Attribute3.y = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("is poor", "is wealthy"), class = "factor"), 
    Attribute4.y = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("has attained a high level of formal education (for example university degree)", 
    "has not attained a high level of formal education (for example never went to school or only attended primary school)"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), .Names = c("ID", "Contest_no", "Option.x", "Chosen_option.x", 
"Combination.x", "Attribute1.x", "Attribute2.x", "Attribute3.x", 
"Attribute4.x", "Option.y", "Chosen_option.y", "Combination.y", 
"Attribute1.y", "Attribute2.y", "Attribute3.y", "Attribute4.y"
))
```

Comment: All joins are done on 2 data frames. Try `full_join(DF1, DF2) %>% full_join(DF3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `dplyr::full_join` with `by=c("ID","Contest_no")` argument as:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- full_join(DF1, DF2, by=c("ID","Contest_no")) %>%
       full_join(DF3, by=c("ID","Contest_no"))
df1
#  V1 V2   V3   V4   V5   V6 ID Contest_no
#1  A  A    A    A    A    A x1          1
#2  B  B <NA> <NA>    B    B x1          2
#3  C  C    C    C    C    C y2          1
#4  D  D    D    D <NA> <NA> y2          2
```

**Updated:** Answer has been modified to consider another column `Option` in `full_join` as:

```
df1 <- full_join(DF1, DF2, by=c("ID","Contest_no", "Option"))
```

**Note:** I had to tweak my `dplyr` to match what is suggested by @Gregor in order to get expected result.

Comment: Hmm, this works for this example, but in my actual--much larger--dataframes, rows get multiplied, so that, if I combined three dataframes, I get six rows of respondent X1...

Comment: @KaC May be it would be better if you can modify your sample data.frame to add additional data which is causing the problem. in the mean time let me check what can be the problem.

Comment: @KaC One reason could be that your data.frames have duplicate  `ID + Contest_no` combination. Do all data frames contain same number of rows?

Comment: No, they have different numbers of rows because of the missing data (as in the original example--I'm now working to update the example to try to replicate the issue).

Comment: @KaC Yes. I can see the updated data. There are duplicate for `ID + Contest_no`. It seems to me that `by=c("ID", "Contest_no", "Option")` will give you correct output.

Comment: @KaC i have checked it at my end. If you execute as `df1 <- full_join(DF1, DF2, by=c("ID","Contest_no", "Option"))` then only `12` rows will be created.

Comment: It does in fact seem to solve the problem. Thank you for your help, @MKR. Was the reason for the multiplication of rows that there were in fact three columns shared across the merged dataframes, or did something else cause this?