# Merging two dataframes in R with missing values and repeated measurements

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have two dataframes that look like this:

```
library(tibble)
df_1 <- tibble(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), y = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b","c", "a", "b", "c"))
df_2 <- tibble(id = c(1,3), z = c(4,6))
```

I want to merge the two dfs such that it looks like this:

```
df_3 <- tibble(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), y = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b","c", "a", "b", "c"), z = c(4,4,4,NA,NA,NA,6,6,6))
```

How will you do so in R? Thank you!

Comment: Just do `df_1 %>% left_join(df_2)` as there are no duplicates for 'id' in 'df_2'.  The previous solution I used sequence only because both datasets had duplicate for the 'id' column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining dataframes with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359343/combining-dataframes-with-missing-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df_1,df_2)
```

Output:

```
     id y         z
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 a         4
2     1 b         4
3     1 c         4
4     2 a        NA
5     2 b        NA
6     2 c        NA
7     3 a         6
8     3 b         6
9     3 c         6
```